# Tracking ecommerce conversions

Tags: google-analytics, linkedin-api

I'm looking to run a PPC campaign on LinkedIn, and I'm just wondering what the best way would be to show how many people that have clicked on ads, have placed an order. LinkedIn don't provide any form of conversion code - and I'm not sure how I could set this up within Google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

use campaign tracking .This is the only way we can track visits from relevant campaign banners. Campaigns in Google Analytics :

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en

Use this line below to create your campaign code.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

use “Campaign Content” to separate banners (names) .

you can use Advance segments to track the number of conversions.